# Add aliases to a query using regex

Tags: php, regex

In a query like this (in postgres):

```
select column1, column2 from table
```

How can I add aliases with uppercase in regex?

```
select column1 "COLUMN1", column2 "COLUMN2" from table
```

I use pg_fetch_array in php, so it is not an option to change the result columns to uppercase

Answer (score 0):

your missing the key word "as" and there is no need for the quotes

```
select column1 AS COLUMN1, column2 AS COLUMN2 from table
```

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html